# "Traversing the View Hierarchy on the iPhone" - what should be this post's fate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Traversing the View Hierarchy on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/751876/1709587) is the 11th-highest-upvoted question on the site to be [closed with no answers but not deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1+duplicate%3A0+locked%3A0+answers%3A0). It's a guide to traversing the view hierarchy in an iOS application, posted as a question. It is, very obviously, not a real question, and was closed as such years ago under the old "not a real question" close reason. And in normal circumstances, I'd happily say "yep, that's the correct outcome", and maybe throw a delete vote its way to try and nudge it a little closer to oblivion.

Except that it looks like a well-written guide, and has 5000 views and 43 upvotes. Clearly, a lot of users saw value in this content, even though it's blatantly in violation of our rules.

Can we, and should we, find a way to save this post? Its author has logged in in the last 24 hours, and so there's hope that we can enlist their help. All we'd need to do is edit the question body to be a question to which the guide is a valid answer, then vote to reopen the question, then have the original author post their guide as an *answer*. Then the content would have a stable home without violating any rules.

I raised a mod flag suggesting roughly this approach, and proposed a question body:

> Given how highly voted this not-really-a-question is, I guess it's been useful over the years; it'd be nice to preserve it and get it into a state where it's actually a Q&A. Luckily, the author is still active. Could you perhaps suggest to the author that a) you edit the question to just read "How can I traverse the view hierarchy of an iOS app?" and then b) you reopen the question and then c) he copies the current content of the "question" and pastes it as an answer?

However, a mod rejected this suggestion (reasonably, I think) on the basis that the resulting question would be too broad:

> The question as such would be too broad, therefore it wouldn't be of much help. Feel free to add your suggestion as a comment on the post. The OP can flag the post to be reopened, if they fix it.

So I'd like to hand off the question of what to do with this post to Meta - and especially to people who know more about iOS stuff than me. These are the things I can't tell:

1. Is the post genuinely good? Does its existence make the internet better, by helping surface information that isn't easily findable elsewhere? And is it still relevant in 2019, or has it become obsolete after a decade of being closed?
2. What good, on-topic question can we pose to which that guide is a valid answer?

If some iOS experts can opine on these points, then hopefully, a decade later, we can decide on a way to bring that post out of the limbo of closure - by either deleting it, or reopening it in a form that complies with the rules.

Comment: Jeff himself (as well as Bill the Lizard) suggested to the asker exactly what needs to be done and... nothing. Maybe the asker forgot. Maybe your comment was all the nudge they needed. Or maybe not and we'll have essentially an abandoned post on our hands.

Comment: @BoltClock Note, though, that the author had less than 24 hours from the first warning to closure. (On a Saturday, during the peak time of year for summer vacations, months after they first posted it.) It's quite likely they never saw that until it was too late for them to have any way to save their post without coordinating with mods via flags or asking on Meta - both tactics that a user with a dozen posts may not know are available. So I don't think it's fair to characterise the author as having previously declined to fix the post; I'm not sure they've ever knowingly had the opportunity.

Comment: Yeah. In that case, it's possible they simply didn't bother since it would have been, in their eyes understandably, too late.

Comment: Take this as a data-point that maybe, just maybe, SO is getting a little too stiff with all its rules-lawyering.

Comment: @jez The fact that we are today reconsidering a closure that happened just after the site's birth a decade ago clearly isn't evidence that we are "getting" too stiff. To such as extent as it's a data-point that shows anything about trends in moderation, logically it shows precisely the *opposite* - although in reality I don't think it shows anything at all.

Comment: Can we have this marked [tag:status-completed] now please?

Comment: @tripleee It's not marked with an actionable tag (e.g. [meta-tag:feature-request] or [meta-tag:bug]), so that would be inappropriate, IMO

Answer (score 21):

Speaking as a person who knows something about iOS, this post has limited value at this point. Closely-related functionality has been built into the IDE's GUI for the past 4 major versions. There's also [a vendor-supplied method to do the same thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION34) as the recommended code.

These and other techniques are described very nicely in a closely-related SO question: [How do I inspect the view hierarchy in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios) (which is both much more viewed and higher-scored than *"Traversing..."*).

I would suggest that, at best, the post you've pointed to should be re-closed as a duplicate of that other question. If it's possible for a mod to convert it to an answer on the other one -- and I don't think it is -- that would be a reasonable solution as well.

Otherwise, I think we can go ahead and remove it; its time is well past.

Comment: If we're going to keep it, we should also remove the outdated use of the \[iphone\] tag and replace it with \[ios\].

Comment: ... and also similarly change "the iPhone" to "iOS" in the title.

Comment: As a quick-fix, if mods allow, one could copy the entire post and post it as community-wiki answer on the proposed dupe target, then delete the question. At least the answer (which is really is imo) is then in the correct place, although it won't get the OP any upvotes. The sole problem I can see with moving it is the loss of votes, meaning it will move to the 11th visible spot on that new answer

Comment: @Adriaan Remember the OP is still active. *If* it's worth reposting the guide as an answer to the other question, we should at least suggest that to the original author and give them a chance to post it under their own account before copying their work across. If they decline or don't respond, *then* maybe it's worth someone else doing so (in a properly-referenced way).

Comment: Marking as a duplicate strikes me as sidestepping an awful lot of the issues here... Done, good call.

Comment: Okey-doke, @Shog9. I'll fix the "iPhone" bits.

Comment: I'd leave the title. Good search keyword

Comment: Fair point; done. @Shog9